# How do I find an element with the 'sponsored-post' class in the HTML content?

Tags: python, html, beautifulsoup

The following code does *not* work because article = 'none', even though variable *articles* has all the listing results.

```
articles = soup.select ('.listingResult')
for article in articles:

    # <div class="listingResult small result2 sponsored-post">
    if (article.find('div', class_='sponsored-post') == None):
```

Comment: Can you share the URL?

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
article.select('div.listingResult.small.result2.sponsored-post')
```

If it does not work, I recommend a better-explained problem and more HTML examples.